# What is the best way to handle the need for multi-processing within a Celery task where the input for the "subtask" is an object?

Tags: python, celery

I wrote a Python script that creates an object that represents a network device.
The object has certain methods that logs into the device and performs network operations (backed by PyATS library).
After most network operations the object runs a disconnect method to disconnect from the device.
The PyATS disconnect can take several moments to complete. To drastically reduce script run time in large environments, I used Threading to issue the disconnect asynchronously in a separate thread (I don't really care when it completes and I don't need any return data).

Now I've moved my script into a Flask app that uses Celery for the heavy lifting.
I've realized now that Celery uses billiards which means I can't use Threading any more.
I thought I would simply call another Celery task to handle the disconnect, but I can't pass a new task my device object (it's not JSON serializable).

Is the best way to handle this to pass a subtask all the individual device information bits in a dict (hostname, ip, credentials, etc etc), let it rebuild the device object and perform the disconnect? Now that I think about it I'm not even sure I can do that since I don't think the new PyATS object would think it's connected....
Or is there a better way?

Comment: You should really use [billiard](https://github.com/celery/billiard) if you use Celery, until they switch to multiprocessing in their code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think about just using billiard.

This is working for me:

```
from billiard import Process

class MyClass:
    ...
    def device_disconnect(self):
        p = Process(target=self.dev.disconnect)
        p.start()
```